# MySQL - my months are current stored 0-11

Tags: mysql, perl, datetime-format

I thought I ran into a bug with MySQL 5.1, but the bug was in the perl code that's creating the timestamps. perl's localtime uses 0-11 for months, but MySQL's datetime uses 1-12. So, I've got all these malformed timestamps that I need to update.

```
2012-00-19 09:03:30
```

This should be:

```
2012-01-19 09:03:30
```

The problem is that the date functions for MySQL return NULL on a 00 month. Is there a way to do this in MySQL?

EDIT: Solution =

```
 UPDATE test_stats 
 SET start_time = CAST(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(start_time, 1, 5), 
                       CAST((CAST(SUBSTRING(start_time, 6, 2) AS UNSIGNED) + 1) AS CHAR(2)),
                       SUBSTRING(start_time, 8, 12)) AS DATETIME);
```

By the way, I was using MySQL 5.1

Comment: OK, I love Perl, but who thought it was a good idea to zero-index months?

Comment: You could try using the [dateadd](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function in MySQL to add a month to each entry. I'm not sure what would happen in the null cases; you'd have to try it on the MySQL command line to find out.

Comment: Perl's gmtime/localtime essentially takes Unix's struct tm as its parameter, and struct tm has zero-indexed months. This is a fairly infamous Perl gotcha, but it's really Unix's fault.

Comment: @JesseSmith Perl will do what you tell it to do. It is zero-indexed so it will be more compatible with conversion by array index, e.g. `$month = $months[$month]` (See perldoc -f localtime). That's raw data, not meant to be used directly in a timestamp. If you still do that, that's not perl's fault, it's your fault.

Comment: @Jonah I think the gotcha with the DATE_ADD is that it adds intervals and doesn't just change integers.  So, in the case of `DATE_ADD('2012-01-30', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)` the result will actually be 2012-02-29. Edge cases, but still there (it was my first thought, too).

Comment: I haven't checked for edge cases like that, that would definitely break the timestamps as well.

Comment: @TLP Good point! Date math is quite quirky at the best of times, though. I guess this is what we get for trying to manipulate dates directly.

Comment: @JesseSmith Or for not debugging properly. You'd think it was obvious the first time you tried it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET DateTimeField = 
    CAST (
     SUBSTRING(DateTimeString, 1, 5) -- '2012-'
   + CAST((CAST(SUBSTRING(DateTimeString, 6, 2) AS INT) + 1) AS VARCHAR) -- '00' => '1'
   + SUBSTRING(DateTimeString, 8, 12) -- '-19 09:03:30'
   AS DATETIME)
```

Test with this select

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(50) = '2012-00-19 09:03:30'

SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@x, 1, 5) 
     + CAST((CAST(SUBSTRING(@x, 6, 2) AS INT) + 1) AS VARCHAR) 
     + SUBSTRING(@x, 8, 12) AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: So, this will update any 00 month, right? To increment all month values, as they are all currently stored as 0-11, I'd first have to update and increment every non-00 month, right?

Comment: Let's see, can I test it first by doing a select: SELECT CAST ( SUBSTRING(DateTimeString, 1, 5) -- '2012-' + CAST((CAST(SUBSTRING(DateTimeString, 6, 2) AS INT) + 1) AS VARCHAR) -- '00' => '1' + SUBSTRING(DateTimeString, 8, 12) -- '-19 09:03:30' AS DATETIME) FROM MyTable;  ?

Comment: @kjprice I added a select for you to be able to test it

Comment: I'm confused by the update statement: DateTimeField and DateTimeString. To be clear: if I have a field called start_time, I would substitute both DateTimeField and DateTimeString with start_time?

Comment: yes you could, if you are updating the same field then both of them are gonna be start_time

Comment: I'm getting a NULL value on the update, any ideas? Also, I had to change INT to UNSIGNED and VARCHAR to CHAR(2)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6867/discussion-between-bassam-mehanni-and-kjprice)